# Django Deploy to AWS EB Show 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am just trying to deploy a sample Django app to AWS EB. I do the exact same with this tutorial=>

[Deploy Django on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#w510aac13c37c15c15b7b2b3b3)

But the result is not the same. I got this error message and May I know how to fix this issue?

[image]

Update

Logs in AWS EB

```
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832250 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.] mod_wsgi (pid=4442): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832304 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.] mod_wsgi (pid=4442): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832387 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832416 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.]   File "/opt/python/current/app/djangotest/djangotest/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832421 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Wed Jan 08 06:48:15.832437 2020] [:error] [pid 4442] [remote 172.31.] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: Got any logging?

Comment: @lain Shelvington, At browser, this is only error, At aws eb logs, has a lot of log type like '/var/log/httpd/error_log' , '/opt/python/log/supervisord.log' and so one, which one is matter?

Comment: @lain Shelvington, Please check update.

Comment: Did you remembder to pip freeze > requirements.txt? And is django in your requirements.txt?

Comment: @OliverAdria, Yes, Finally I found the error this is because of the requirements.txt file name is not correct. I forget to put s in requirement.txt and should be requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeStar in order to deploy a Django 3.1.5+ & Python 3.8 app on AWS. I wrote a tutorial [here](https://dev.to/robertseghedi/the-no-stress-django-continuous-deployment-on-amazon-web-services-no-terminal-4da0).

There is no code or terminal needed.

1 - First of all, go to your AWS Console, press Option + S (Mac) and type CodeStar

[image: Step 1]

2 - Then, press the Create project button

[image: Step 2]

3 - Select your options, these are the ones that worked well for me

[image: Step 3]

4 - Select (click) the platform that showed up and press Next

[image: Step 4]

5 - Enter your project name & id, and select your repo (I'm using Github - btw it supports continuous deployment)

[image: Step 5]

6 - If you chose Github, you will have to enter these details. AWS will automatically create a repo for you.

[image: Step 6]

7 - Quickly configure your EC2 Instance

[image: Step 7]

8 - Review your project information and click on Create project

[image: Step 8]

At this point, you will have to wait 3-4 minutes for AWS to make everything for you.

When you push something to your repo on Github, the CodePipeline will automatically update your website.

The default Django version that AWS installs is 3.1.5, but you can modify the common.txt requirements-file from /requirements to 3.1.7, if you want.